# Getting Error {"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, cloudera

I have setup CHD4 on my EC2 Instances. Everything is working fine.

When I try to access : http://ec2-00-000-000-000.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:50075/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETHOMEDIRECTORY I am getting below error :

{"RemoteException":{"exception":"IllegalArgumentException","javaClassName":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","message":"namenoderpcaddress is not specified."}}

I have even tried with  http://ec2-00-000-000-000.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:50070/webhdfs/v1 which says me :

HTTP ERROR 404 NOT_FOUND

Problem accessing /webhdfs. Reason:
NOT_FOUND

I have also enabled dfs.webhdfs.enabled property but no luck.

My basic goal is to load data from my windows machine to HDFS where my Client program is sitting on my windows machine.

Any Idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You might need to do something with the `dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address` config property for Amazon.  Check the Namenode->Advanced configuration in Cloudera Manager

Comment: Ok, dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address=8022. Namenode->Advanced configuration in Cloudera Manager has WebHDFS is enabled. and other parameters looks good. I don't understand what you mean by "config property for Amazon"?

Comment: 8022 is just the port.  Was it empty before?

Comment: can you ping ec2-00-000-000-000.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com?

Comment: @climbage : No not it was not empty.

Comment: @JtheRocker : Yes I am able to ping

Comment: @Dhams: May I know what IP address ec2-00-000-000-000.us west-1.compute.amazonaws.com resolves to?

Comment: @Dhams.  Try setting it to empty.  Just having the port # doesn't seem right to me

Comment: @climbage: Do you want to me to set dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address=8022 empty?

Comment: I think it's worth a shot

Comment: @climbage : Clouldera Manager does not allow me to set dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address as empty. I tried blank and # value.

Answer (score 2):

for the sake of posterity, you need to pass the namenoderpcaddress parameter at the end, something like:

```
curl -v -i "http://<host>:50075/webhdfs/v1/my/path/to/file?op=OPEN&namenoderpcaddress=<host>:8022"
```